# Unable to get bound-field value in ASP.NET GridView when deleting

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to get the value returned by a row-delete event attached to a bound-field in `GridView`.  However, I am getting the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

My code:

```
protected void gvBankDetails_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string slno = (TextBox)gvBankDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
}

<asp:GridView ID="gvBankDetails" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
    OnRowEditing="gvBankDetails_RowEditing"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="gvBankDetails_RowCancelingEdit"
    OnRowUpdating="gvBankDetails_RowUpdating"
    OnRowDeleting="gvBankDetails_RowDeleting" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="sl no" DataField="id" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />
    </Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvBankDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex];


       string text = row.Cells[1].Text; //where n starts at 0
```